# Import external seed data

Tags: laravel

I wish to split a massive seed file into external files.

How can I a) set up the external file and b) import that file.

I've tried namespacing the external file but that does not appear to work.

The file is located inside a folder in my seeds directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespacing actually is the solution, but only on the split files. You still need a single Seeder to call the others. By default, Laravel has `DatabaseSeeder.php`:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
  public function run() {
    $this->call(ExampleSeeder::class);
    ...
  }
}
```

`ExampleSeeder` is a non-namespaced file located in `database/seeds/ExampleSeeder.php`.

Running the command `php artisan db:seed` will use the `DatabaseSeeder.php` class to run all the seeds referenced in `public function run()`. Now that we understand that, we can add "external" seeds. Given the structure:

```
- database
  - seeds
    - external
      - ExternalExampleSeeder.php
  - DatabaseSeeder.php
  - ExampleSeeder.php
```

If you try to add `$this->call(ExternalExampleSeeder::class);`, you'll get the error:

> Target class [ExternalExampleSeeder] does not exist.

To solve this, you need to namespace and import the seed:

```
// ExternalExampleSeeder.php
<?php
namespace App\Database\Seeds\External;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class ExternalExampleSeeder extends Seeder {
  ...
}

// DatabaseSeeder.php
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Database\Seeds\External\ExternalExampleSeeder;
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
  public function run() {
    $this->call(ExampleSeeder::class);
    $this->call(ExternalExampleSeeder::class);
    ...
  }
}
```

Then run `php artisan db:seed`, then it should have no issue.

So the solution is to leave the `DatabaseSeeder.php` and default seeds as non-namespaced, and namespace and import the ones in `database/seeds/external` (or whatever your directory is called).

Comment: Thanks, sorry I should have been clearer, I'd like to access that file in my seed, not in the seeder and import the data from the external class into that seeder.

Comment: Hmm, I think I get what you're saying, but the rule should still apply; as long as the external file is namespaced and imported appropriately, it should work as expected. Beyond that, might need a code example of what you've got added to the question.

Comment: I think your answer, answers my poorly worded question, so I'll ask a new question with more detail, sorry! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217440/how-can-i-use-a-var-inside-another-class

Comment: Haha no worries; I didn't think it was poorly worded, but I see what you're asking in the other question. Cheers!