# How can I use a var inside another class?

Tags: laravel

I have a class setup like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Database\Seeds\Tags;

class Users
{
    public $data = [
        [
....
```

In another class I:

```
use App\Database\Seeds\Tags\Phones;
```

Then try `Phones::class::data` or `Phones::data` but still can't get the external data array.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `$data` is an instance variable; so in order to access it, you'd need to do something like `(new Users)->data`

Comment: That's because it's not a static property. You can get the `$data` only from an instance of the `Users` class.

Comment: So if I make it static, the above should work?

Comment: Just made $data static, and it does not work.

Comment: you would need to reference the static variable from `Users` like this `Users::$data`

Comment: Yes ive referenced like that with no luck

Comment: The other way would maybe be to create a getter function that is static and returns the ```$data``` value.

Comment: That does not appear to work either - does anyone have a concrete example?

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo or not, but you've got `class Users`, but you're referencing as `use App\Database\Seeds\Tags\Phones;`, `Phones::class::data` and `Phones::data`. That would explain the error (`Phones != Users`), unless it's just a copy-paste issue for this question.

Comment: Ah that will be a copy and paste error - sorry

Comment: I guessed as much, but better to check. Anyway, following the import, `use App\Database\Seeds\Tags\Phones`, you _should_ be able to do `$data = (new Phones())->data;`, as long as `$data` is `public`. Or, `$phones = new Phones();`, then later in the code, `$data = $phones->data;`. Etc etc. Try that, and if that doesn't work, include any errors.

Comment: I just get class not found despite having the correct namespace.